# How can I ingest fake/test Windows logs into ELK run on a RHEL machine?

Tags: kibana, dashboard, elk

I'm attempting to create custom dashboards within Kibana to represent captured Windows logs. Due to limitations, the only testing instance of ELK I have is a single node system run on a RHEL8 vm through VMware. The free version of VMware does not allow for multiple VMs to be run at the same time, so the only logs ELK is ingesting are from the linux machine it sits on.

Creating the dashboards without any data is possible, but it's hard for me to actually keep track of and visualize what I'm creating. **Without a windows machine to monitor, I want to download some testing/sample logs so I can have something to visualize as I customize dashboards. How do I accomplish this?**